# How can I add a footer at the end of this website?

Tags: html, css, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a footer at the end of this website but for some reason it appears above the products :

[image: bad footer screenshot]

And when I change the browser size :

[image: resized page screenshot]

But I want a footer like this :

[image: good footer screenshot]

Here is my code :

**HTML :**

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #36454F;">
    {% for i in p%} 
 
    <div class='card'>
      <div class="number">{{i.Number}}</div>
      <img src="{{i.image}}"></img>
      <p id="id">{{i.description}}</p>
      <a href="{{i.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
        <button><span class="price"> ${{i.price}}</span> buy</button>
      </a>
    </div>
 
    {%endfor%}
    
    <div class="footer">
        <h3>hello</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS :**

```css
.card {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  position:  relative;
  top: 611px;
  margin-bottom: 33px;
  margin-right: 33px;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 130px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: red;
}

.card img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.price {
  background-color: #f44336;
  font-size:22px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative ;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 44px;
  align-items: center;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: .5;
  background-color: #330;
}

#id {
  background-color: palevioletred;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.number {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #330;
  color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  right: -22px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 22px;
}

@media (max-width: 1864px) {
  .card {
    max-width: 300px;
  }

  .price {
    font-size:20px;
  }

  .card img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

I tried to set a negative `bottom` property to push it to the end :

```css
.footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -674px;
  height: 130px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it didn't help. How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Nowadays there is absolutely no reason to use `float: left` to layout content in the way you show. You should use `flex` or `grid` layout instead. Using `float` leads to various problems like the one you show in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To set the footer to the bottom of the page, you need to use this CSS:

```
.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf; /* Set your own background */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stay at the bottom of the page and stretch along the bottom, I'd do something like this with the CSS

```
.footer {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: (whatever you want);
color: (color of the text, whatever you want);
text-align: center; /*unless you want the text aligned differently*/
}
```

Also look up how to use the grid-container if you want the items of the footer in rows like the example you gave.

Answer (score 0):

You need the footer tag to do its job!

Read more about the footer tag here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html5-footer-tag/

Reference: https://code-boxx.com/keep-html-footers-at-bottom/

---

**The easy ways to keep a footer at the bottom with modern CSS are:**

1. Use footer `{ position: fixed}` or `footer { position: sticky }` to
   keep the  at the bottom.
2. Use a flexbox layout that "stretches" the body section, keep the
   footer at the bottom.

   `body{ display: flex; flex-direction: column; }`

   `main{ flex-grow: 1; }`
3. Lastly, use a grid layout to achieve the same "stretch body
   section".

   `<header>HEAD</header> <main>MAIN</main> <footer>FOOT</footer>`

   `html, body { height: 100%;}`

   `body { disply: grid; grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto; }`

Comment: A `footer` tag is there for semantic information, but it does not help you with creating such a layout.

Comment: I am sorry! Let me edit the answer so it helps everybody.