# how can i prevent the footer from changing its position when resizing the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my website with the dimention of 6443-4840 :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX6Rs.png)

but in smaller sizes the footer is no longer a footer.

website with the dimention of 2920-2386:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfetD.png)

in every window sizes i want the postition of the footer to be at the same position in dimention of 6443-4840, then i can say i have a footer but currently in bigger window sizes the footer is in a correct position and as long as i change the window size the footer overlaps the other content.

```css
 


body{

  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 500px; /* Height of the footer */
}  
footer{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: grey;
}

.card {
  
  max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  position:  relative;
  top: 611px;
  margin-bottom: 33px; 
  margin-right: 33px;
  float: left;

}

 




.card img{

  height: 400px; 
    width: 400px;
  vertical-align: middle;
 
 
}

.price {background-color: #f44336;
    font-size:22px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 3px;




}

.card button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative ;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 44px;
  align-items: center;



  


}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: .5;
  background-color: #330;


}
 

#id{
    background-color: palevioletred;
    color: white;   
    margin: 0; 
    font-size: 17px;
}
 
 
.number{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #330;
    color: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -22px;
    right: -22px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 22px;

}

 

@media  (max-width: 1864px){
    .card{
        max-width: 300px;
    }
     
    .price{

        font-size:20px;

    }

    .card img{
        height: 300px; 
        width: 300px;

    }

     



}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
    <h1>header</h1>
    
</head>
<body style="background-color: #36454F;">




    {% for i in p%} 
 
                <div class='card'>
                    <div class="number">{{i.Number}}</div>
                    <img src="{{i.image}}"></img>
                    <p id="id">{{i.description}}</p>
                    <a href="{{i.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                        <button><span class="price"> ${{i.price}}</span> buy</button>
                    </a>    




                </div>



 
    {%endfor%}

    <footer class="footer">
        <h3 >hello</h3>

    </footer>    

</body>
</html>
```

how can i solve this problem?(i do not want a fixed footer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a footer at the end of this website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72451984/how-can-i-add-a-footer-at-the-end-of-this-website)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1>Fixed Footer</h1>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
```